# For..of with Symbol.asyncIterator

Tags: javascript

Why Symbol.asyncIterator is not working?

```
const obj = {
  async *[Symbol.asyncIterator] () {
    yield 10;
    yield 100;
    yield 1000;
  },
};
```

```
for (const val of obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

> error: TypeError: obj is not iterable

```
for await (const val of obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

> error: SyntaxError: for await (... of ...) is only valid in async functions and async generators

```
(async() => {
  for await (const val of obj) {
    console.log(val);
  }
})()
```

> error: SyntaxError: for await (... of ...) is only valid in async functions and async generators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's an async iterable, you need to await each value:

```
for await (const val of obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}
```

NOTE: this all needs to be wrapped in an async function because Node.js doesn't support top-level await by default:

```
(async() => {
  for await (const val of obj) {
    console.log(val);
  }
})()
```

Comment: error: SyntaxError: for await (... of ...) is only valid in async functions and async generators

Comment: Ok, it works, how do you think why it is not working on this resource https://playcode.io/, I have tested this code there, and you answer is not working there

Answer (score 0):

Use await in an async function

```js
const obj = {
  async * [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {
    yield 10;
    yield 100;
    yield 1000;
  },
};

(async() => {
  for await (const val of obj) {
    console.log(val);
  }
})()
```

Comment: How is this answer different than @frozen's? The _PS_ note covers the top-level await caveat

Comment: @customcommander I guess you've never submitted an answer you were working on while another happened to get posted at same time?

Comment: I actually have. When it truly is the same answer I do delete it. Just pointing it out in case you'd like to do the same.

Comment: Just to finish on a constructive note: when you say `Use await in an async function` I find that misleading and doesn't address the _original_ issue. OP wasn't using the right JS construct (`for..of` _vs_ `for await .. of`) for an object implementing an async iteration protocol. Your answer doesn't mention that which is a shame IMHO. (For the record I neither +1 nor -1 this answer)

Comment: @customcommander Feel free to edit. Seems self explanatory with a working example that is all of 4- 5 lines of very simple to read code